# xrange generating strings? I don't get it

Tags: python, for-loop, xrange

For some reason, the x variable in the first `for...` loop changes from `int` to `str` after a single iteration through the code. I'm baffled as to why that must be, but each time I run this script, my set ends up being populated by strings consisting of hundreds of zeros.

In case anyone is curious, this is an attempt to solve Euler's question 4.

```
# A palindromic number reads the same both ways.
# The largest palindrome made from the product
# of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 99.
# Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

def palindrome():

    products = set()

    for x in xrange(700,999):
        for y in xrange(700,999):
            temp = x*y
            n = [x for x in str(temp)]
            if temp not in products:
                if len(n)%2 == 0:
                    half = len(n)/2
                    first = n[:half]
                    last = n[half:]
                    last.reverse()
                    if first == last:
                        products.add(temp)

    return products



if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = palindrome()
    print n
```

Comment: @InbarRose: the OP says he's doing [Project Euler's question #4](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4)

Answer (score 7):

In python 2.x, list comprehensions leak their variable to the enclosing scope.  So your list comprehension `[x for x in str(temp)]` overwrites the value of x.  But note that it will get set back to an int at the next iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

It changes to a string because *you* assing a string to it:

```
        n = [x for x in str(temp)]
```

Mistakes like these are the reason why you should avoid one letter variables. That being said, I usually use `_` as the throwaway variable in list comprehensions...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use x inside the following list comprehension `n = [x for x in str(temp)]`. Just pick another variable name instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
1    for x in xrange(700,999):
2        for y in xrange(700,999):
3            temp = x*y
4            n = [x for x in str(temp)]
```

after step#4, n = ['4', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0'], x = '0'

then for next step#3, temp='0'*701